# Transfer Contact along with Account when Ownership changes

Tags: account, contact, assignment-rules, ownership

**Background:** when an Account is transferred manually, Salesforce takes care of also transferring all contacts to the new owner. However, when this happens using a mass upload, we can’t accomplish this

**Requirements:**

Is there a native function within SF that can help me achieve this so contacts are updated simultaneously?

Or if there’s a tool or Salesforce feature that can do that, is anybody aware of such a tool?

Thanks

Comment: [SFDMU](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SFDX-Data-Move-Utility) can do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Mass Transfer record from the setup.

Via this, when you bulk transfer the accounts, all its related contacts also get transfer automatically to respective new owner.

Also you get multiple option while transferring. for e.g., if you want you can transfer the Open Opportunities not by owned by existing user, closed opportunities, open cases, closed cases, etc.

For detail refer this [enter link description here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_transfer.htm&type=5)

Alternate way is to use the Data Loader. You can create & Download a report of account which needs to be transfer. Also the report of contact for those account. And then you can use the new owner id and then update the both Account and contact. But this process will take more time.